# Firebase ML Kit: Label Detector causing rapid increase in memory consumption

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

## UPDATE 2:

Method I'm using to Scale Bitmaps.

```
private fun Bitmap.getResizedBitmap(maxWidth: Int, minWidth: Int, maxHeight: Int, minHeight: Int): Bitmap =
    when {
        width <= minWidth || height <= minHeight -> this
        maxHeight > 0 && maxWidth > 0 -> {
                val bitmapWidth = width
                val bitmapHeight = height
                val ratioBitmap = bitmapWidth.toFloat() / bitmapHeight.toFloat()
                val ratioMax = maxWidth.toFloat() / maxHeight.toFloat()

                var finalWidth = maxWidth.toFloat()
                var finalHeight = maxHeight.toFloat()
                if (ratioMax > ratioBitmap) finalWidth = maxHeight.toFloat() * ratioBitmap
                else finalHeight = maxWidth.toFloat() / ratioBitmap
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(this, finalWidth.toInt(), finalHeight.toInt(), true)
            }
            else -> this
        }
```

## UPDATE 1:

```
override fun detectInPhoto(context: Context, uri: Uri, onLabelled: (List<Label>) -> Unit) {
    try {
        labelDetector.detectInImage(FirebaseVisionImage.fromFilePath(context, uri))
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Log.d("LabelDetector", "${e.message}")
        }
```

**StackTrace:**

```
07-24 12:59:25.566 23076-23164/com.sev7en.curator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
Process: com.sev7en.curator, PID: 23076
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 24140812 byte allocation with 4185968 free bytes and 18MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:564)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:587)
    at com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImage.getBitmapForDebugging(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.ml.vision.label.FirebaseVisionLabelDetector.detectInImage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sev7en.curator.ai.image.FirebasePhotoLabelDetector.detectInPhoto(FirebasePhotoLabelDetector.kt:52)
    at com.sev7en.curator.util.impl.PhotoLabelManagerImpl$onUnlabelledPhotosReceived$1$2.doResume(PhotoLabelManagerImpl.kt:119)
    at kotlin.coroutines.experimental.jvm.internal.CoroutineImpl.resume(CoroutineImpl.kt:42)
    at kotlin.coroutines.experimental.jvm.internal.CoroutineImpl.resume(CoroutineImpl.kt:41)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.DispatchedTask$DefaultImpls.run(Dispatched.kt:161)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.AbstractContinuation.run(AbstractContinuation.kt:31)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1388)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:251)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:845)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1674)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1629)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:108)
```

The error is here: `com.sev7en.curator.ai.image.FirebasePhotoLabelDetector.detectInPhoto(FirebasePhotoLabelDetector.kt:52)`.

If I comment it out, there is not issue. Same issue with a Bitmap that I provide.

## Original Post

I'm using the following method to get a FirebaseVisionLabelDetector:

```
fun getLabelDetector(options: FirebaseVisionLabelDetectorOptions?): FirebaseVisionLabelDetector =
    FirebaseVision.getInstance()
        .getVisionLabelDetector(options ?: getLabelDetectorOptions(0.7f))
```

Using it like this:

```
fun getLabels(bitmap : Bitmap){
getLabelDetector.detectInImage(FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap))
}
```

But from looking at the memory in Android Profiler, I noticed that a lot of memory was getting allocated for the Bitmaps provided and their references weren't being removed, therefore they weren't Garbage Collected. I maintain no reference of the Bitmap myself. The overall memory usage keeps increasing with every method call.

**I've ignored the result of the function as I want to improve it's performance first.**

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. Our engineers are taking a look at this. Will get back to you soon!

Comment: Alright @PannagSanketi, thank you!

Comment: Anything @PannagSanketi?

Comment: @ChrisRohitBrendan, we cannot repro what you described. I tried detection with 37MB images repeatedly and it worked fine. Could you 1) paste your code how did you get your Bitmap? 2) If the image came from a file, could you try FirebaseVisionImage.fromFilePath? 3) If you are running a loop with a bunch of images, could you comment out your call to ML Kit and see the impact to memory? Let me know results of above 1)-3) and I can take a further look. Thanks.

Comment: @IsabellaChen please see the updated post with the stacktrace.

Comment: @ChrisRohitBrendan Are you running this in a loop? How large are your image files (and what format they are)? How many times did you run in a loop before the crash? Bitmap is uncompressed and takes a large chunk of memory. If you run in a loop, could you wait till one result come back before feed in another image?

Comment: @IsabellaChen the files vary in size some depending some 3MB each. Formats are Gifs, Jpeg, Png, but got the crash while testing with only Jpegs and Pngs. I am running a loop, but I don't want to wait before feeing another ideally since the process is slow. What is the expected resolution by the model, that way I can compress and then send them?

Comment: @ChrisRohitBrendan I replied in Answer. Please take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Bitmaps do consume a lot of memory. The ML Kit SDK starts holding reference to images when detection is initiated and releases reference after detection is done. If you start many detection in parallel, memory could potentially be exhausted.

Inside the SDK, given all detection are computation intensive, all the async calls are executed sequentially. So starting 2nd detection after 1st detection is done won't actually slow things down. And it's more memory efficient to do it that way.

ML Kit returns a Task<> for its async APIs and you can chain operations easily (and recursively) See Task documentation:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks#chaining

Or simply addOnCompletetionListener and call a helper function to start detection again.

Comment: As you suggested, I've made it so that I wait for a result before I feed another image and I'm not longer getting OOM's. I've also been scaling bitmaps down before sending them and I'm getting different results, and a performance bump if they are scaled down. Please either have the API compress and scale the Bitmap itself, or tell me how to go about compressing the Bitmap before feeding it in.

Comment: @ChrisRohitBrendan Which resolution did you scale the Bitmap to? We cannot suggest an absolute value since models might be improved along the way. At this moment, scaling to a resolution > 224 * 224 should not impact inference quality.

Comment: Scaling down to 224 * 224, since most other models use this standard, misses some results and gets a lot of labels wrong. If I use .fromFilePath instead I get better results, or scale the bitmap to about 448, or 896. I've included the method I'm using to scale in the post.